# How to find the radius of this middle circle arranged as shown.

Tags: geometry, circles

There is this maths competition geometry problem and my approach[image].

And this is my initial approach.

[image]

From the picture, the shaded circle looks slightly bigger.

What we are looking for is the $x$ which is half of the length of the side of the red square. But it seems that we have two unknowns, the $x$ and the hypotenuse of the triangle.

Are there any other way besides this? Or any useful theorem? But I don't think it is that complicated.

Many many thanks! Helps are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint without words (except these):

[image]

Comment: wow, this is beautiful! thanks! I apologise if I cannot see this at a glance, but why is the top right triangle with red base an isosceles triangle? that is the only thing that I need to know.

Comment: @user71346: The red-edged triangle is isosceles because the (entire) figure is symmetric across the "diagonal" line $\overleftrightarrow{OP}$, where $O$ is the center of the target circle, and $P$ is the midpoint of that triangle's hypotenuse.

Comment: @user71346: The new image should make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the shaped circle is $( \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} - 2 )\times 110 \approx 126.089080693617$ units.

For simplicity of derivation, let us rescale all the unshaded circles to have radius $1$.
Let $r$ be the radius of the shaded circle. If we choose the coordinate system
such the the shaded circle is centered at $A = (0, 0)$ and the $x$-axis passing through the nearest unshaded circles on its right, the centers of 3 of the unshaded circles on its right are given by

$$B = (r+1,0),\; C = (r+3,0)\quad\text{ and }\quad D = (x_D,y_D) = (r+2,\sqrt{3})$$

Construct a line passing through $A$ tangent to the circle centered at $D$. Let the line
touch the circle at point $E = (x_E,y_E)$. By symmetry, it is clear $\angle BAE = 45^\circ$. It is easy to see

$$
\begin{cases}
x_E &= x_D - \cos45^\circ = r + 2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
y_E &= y_D + \sin45^\circ = \sqrt{3} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{cases}
$$
As a result,
$$\angle BAE = 45^\circ
\quad\implies\quad
x_E = y_E
\quad\implies\quad 
r = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} - 2$$

Following is a figure illustrating the arrangement of the circles.
The unshaded/shaded circles in question have been colored in red/blue in this figure.

$\hspace1in$ [image: Tangent to 3 Triangles]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Sorry, not good at diagrams so will answer in words, but I'm sure you can draw your own diagram.

Look at the five circles which form a "ring" in the top left of the diagram.  Specifically, start with the shaded circle then go left, up/left, up/right, down/right and down to the shaded circle again.  Call the centres of the circles $A,B,C,D,E$ respectively.  Then you should be able to work out the lengths $BC,\,CD,\,DE$, and you can see that $AB=EA$.  You should also be able to find the five angles in the pentagon, and this will be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind I just want to check my doubt, is angle BCD equal to angle CDE? Then is angle CBE=180-BCD? and DEB=CBE? if they are all true, I am trying to use the sum of inner angle formula, but it ended up the $\alpha$ being cancel, so I cannot find $\alpha$? Thanks.

Comment: I believe everything you have said in your comment is correct.  Your diagram has lots of $60^\circ$ angles and $90^\circ$ angles, this should help you find the exact dimensions.